# Desenvolvimento de aplicativos móveis em Python

Tags: python, windows-phone, mobile

Há como desenvolver para sistemas operacionais móveis com o Python (Android, Windows Phone e iOS)? Como inicio isso? Softwares a utilizar etc. Meu foco principal é o Windows Phone.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [**Kivy**](http://kivy.org/#home), é disponível para Linux, Windows, OS X, Android e iOS e é  gratuito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para Android existe o Kivy (http://kivy.org/) mas até onde sei não funciona para Windows Phone. Se deseja algo para desenvolver para multi-plataformas mobile dê uma olhada em http://ionicframework.com/, não é python, e sim javascript mais markup. No caso do Windows Phone, por enquanto a melhor opção é usar alguma linguagens suportadas pela plataforma .NET